# Eclipse: Why is it eating my log4j.properties file?

Tags: eclipse, ant

Windows 7 Professional

Eclipse 3.7.2

I am migrating over to Eclipse from another IDE.  I am compiling my project with the same ANT build.xml file I was using before.  I do it by

1. highlighting my project in the project view
2. expanding the tree node
3. finding my build.xml file there
4. right clicking my build.xml file
5. choosing Run as > Ant Build

Works great, but every few builds Eclpise eats my log4j.properties file located at:

C:\AllProjects\Workspace\acme\war\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.properties

Eclipse basically eats all files in WEB-INF\classes that are not *.class files.

What am I doing to make this happen and how can I stop it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After selecting  in Project explorer:

Properties > Java Compiler > Building > Output Folder

Uncheck "Scrub output folders when cleaning projects"

It is a solution for me ( though maybe not everyone ) because I use a time test ANT build.xml to do my compiling, building and cleaning for me.   I just leave Eclipse's auto builds on so I get those nice error notifications as a I type, before I compile.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using ant instead of Eclipse to build, you could try turning off the setting to build the project automatically.

Select your project, then in the menu bar at the top of the screen, select `Project` and uncheck the `Build Automatically` option.

**Edit: Second opinion**

I would add an ant task to copy the log4j property file into your `WEB-INF/classes` folder every time you do a build.  One nice advantage of this is that you can have a different property file for different build types (debug, release, *etc.*) and not worry about manually making changes to it.  Also, this should make it easier to manage if you're using version control.

Copy your `log4j.properties` file to your source directory and add something like this to your ant build file:

```
<target name="copy-log4j-property-file">
    <copy file="src/log4j.properties" todir="WEB-INF/classes" />
</target>

<target name="build" depends="copy-log4j-property-file">
    <!-- the rest of your build things here -->
</target>
```

Comment: But if I do that wont I lose that nifty Eclipse feature of highlighting errors while I edit and before I compile?

Comment: You're right.  I added another suggestion to my answer that involves adding another target to your ant file to copy the file each time you do a build.